# Automatically split a part for separate extruders

Tags: slicing

Hopefully this isn't too vague, but I have a question I just can't figure out:

We're in the midst of possibly designing a new printer.  I can't give too many of the details away except that its somewhat like an "IDEX" printer where different extruders will print different parts of a print.

Now I understand how to split an .stl into two and assign extruders to each area.  I have a Prusa with an MMU on it and I also have access to a J750 that does something similar. I've split things in Blender and imported them as assemblies of stl's, where each stl is assigned a material.  My question is more like:

-If I wanted to split a part by location and assign extruders, and I wanted to do this quickly ***in a slicing software*** (instead of in a cad software prior to getting into the slicing software), is this possible?  **Is there a software (Cura/PrusaSlicer/something else) that already does this?** I.e.  the 'right-most' part of the print will be one extruder, the 'left-most' will be another.  Something like this:

[image]

P.s. I know in PrusaSlicer you can "paint" where a material will be, but this would be more of a "chop"

Comment: Is this a use case that you are trying to solve for or is this only to test the printer? I'm struggling to see where you might use this function in a real print. Seems like it will just introduce print quality issue and Z-seam for no gain.

Comment: Also if you expect users to do this split with all models you will limit them to only slicers that can do this.

Comment: Slic3r/Prusaslicer has some tools where you call out shapes superimposed over the print, like resizable cubes, and these make zones where you can load separate slicing profiles just for what is in the cube(s). Maybe you could define a different extruder for two profiles and assign them to the part that way?